# Controlling digital potentiometer as feedback resistor in transimpedance amplifier

Tags: arduino, digital-potentiometer, transimpedance

**Main Idea:** I have designed a transimpedance amplifier for current-to-voltage conversion application. To increase the dynamic range of the input current that can be measured, I have integrated the digital potentiometer as the feedback resisitor and controlling the resistance value on Arduino microcontroller. **Problem:** The transimpedance output voltage is being compared to another voltage signal and then the TIA output is being levelized to be within the same range of the other voltage signal by varying the potentiometer values. But, the output value is keep on increasing and until it reaches a certain value and then starting back from zero again like a loop. How do stop and stabilize the output value once it reaches a certain point. I have attached the schematic& code below:
[image]

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 9, 5, 4, 3, 2);
int CS1= 10;
int pot= 1;

void setup() {
  // setup the dig. pot.
  pinMode (CS1, OUTPUT);
  SPI.begin();
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  int sensorValue2= analogRead(A1);
  // Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
  float voltage = (sensorValue-sensorValue2) * (5.0 / 1023.0);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print(voltage);
  float voltage2 = analogRead(A2)* (5.0 / 1023.0);

  while(voltage >= voltage2 - 0.05){
    pot++;
    digitalPotWriteRed(pot);
  }

}

void digitalPotWriteRed(int value){
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(14000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  digitalWrite(CS1, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(B00010001);
  SPI.transfer(value);
  digitalWrite(CS1, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();}
```

Comment: Where's the schematic ? No schematic means no answer. I for sure am too lazy to visualize how you connected things based on your text.

Comment: Use variables as boundary limits such that if voltage 2 is inside the boundaries the correction loop (pot++) will not run. You have to teach a feedback loop when to stop chasing its tail. Also a schematic would be helpful, as hardware errors can create the same effect.

Comment: Semiconductor potentiometers may not behave in totally expected ways if they are used as single ended resistors.  I have not tried to figure out your circuit but try and find out if you can modify the circuit to incorporate the other half of the pot into R4 or R8 so both sides are used.  See if you can find a similar adjustable circuit that uses a pot instead of a resistor.  The resistance value is not as well defined as the resistance ratio usually and may drift or so it was in the olden days.